# Why are these 'p' tags appearing on the frontend of Bolt entry?

Tags: html, bolt-cms

Does anyone know why these 'p' tags aren't parsing correctly on the frontend of my Bolt installation? This was my first entry on a brand new installation of Bolt that I setup for testing purposes. I haven't changed any settings. It's kind of weird that this would be the default behavior in my opinion. Any advice?

Frontend
[image: Frontend]

Backend
[image: Backend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1.**

Hey you may have found this already, but bolt is somewhat anoying at times. in your "what you see is what you get" editor, click Source. there it would display the  `<p>` tags. you may delete them here.

**Solution 2.**

I take you use twig for parsing the data on your site. use something like `{{ Item.Parse|raw }}` The RAW tag will output HTML as html tags and not as text

Didnt understand if u wanted the tags to output as HTML or get rid of them. so put 2 answers down.

Hope this helps.